# How to loop array by excluding specific item?

Tags: arrays, swift, loops, for-loop

I want to exclude specific item (without removing)from an array and loop the remaining.
For example

```
var array = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

let's say I want to loop the array but don't wanna include 4 (item at 4th position). How can I do it?

Comment: So is your question about Python or Swift? Why did you tag 2 completely unrelated languages?

Comment: In an algorithm logic, you could iterate, but check the index/value each time to see if you need to continue or not.

Comment: @DávidPásztor Swift. Well, you can loop an array in both languages so.

Comment: @abi, you could in many languages, but the constructs available are different in each...

Comment: If your question is about a specific language, you shouldn't tag another language just because that language also supports the same behaviour.

Comment: Sometimes simple thing can cause a problem! Thanks for solution @DávidPásztor and sorry for tagging two different languages, next time it ain't gonna happen, mate.

Answer (score 2):

There is the `where` clause to control the loop.

If you want to omit the **value** 4

```
let array = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
for item in array where item != 4 {
    print(item)
}
```

If you want to omit the value at **index** 4

```
let array = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
for (index, item) in array.enumerated() where index != 4 {
    print(item)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

swift version:

you can use `enumerated()` and check the index

```
var array = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
for (index, item) in array.enumerated() {
    
    if index == 4 {
        continue
    }
    
    print(item)    
}
```

Comment: Note that the offset has no relation with the collection index. They are completely different things. They just happen to be equal if you are working with arrays. Not all collections starts at zero. This wouldn't work if it where a subsequence of the original array/collection.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `filter` to exclude specific elements from the array and call it on `enumerated()` so that you can check the index of each element, then exclude the element with the unwanted index.

```
let items = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
let filtered = items.enumerated().filter { $0.offset != 3 }.map(\.element)
for item in filtered {
    print(item)
}
```

Output:

```
1
2
3
5
6
```

Comment: this is extremely inefficient